# Why is 'git clone' not working with submodule?

Tags: git, github, gitlab, git-submodules

I could not clone the parent project with submodules. Only parent project was cloned.

I tried with

1. git clone --recurse-submodules <repor>
2. git clone --recursive <repo

And so many options.

Do I need to configure my Git environment to support submodules?

Here it is repositories I have tried.

##### Parent project

https://github.com/chamlyidunil/test-submodule-project

##### Common project (submodule)

https://github.com/chamlyidunil/common-utility

And it really helps you if you can provide example Git commands for the whole cycle.

1. git pull (get update with sub modules)

My Git version is 2.15.1 (Apple Git-101).

Comment: Are you passing `--recurse-submodules` to `git pull`?

Comment: Yes I did try those options.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "didn't work"? What is the actual outcome? An error message? Unexpected behavior? You need to provide as much detail as possible when asking a question. Just saying that something "didn't work" is not enough for people reading this question.

Comment: it just clone parent project. it not cloning submodules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your project has a `.gitmodules` file, but it doesn't have an actual submodule commit checked in.

If you want to add a submodule, you should use `git submodule add` to add the submodule and then commit the result.  That will add the submodule commit into the repository, which your repository is lacking at the moment.

So, for example, in your personal clone of the parent project, you'd remove the current `.gitmodules` file and run `git submodule add https://github.com/chamlyidunil/common-utility.git common-utility` and then commit the result.

Comment: Thanks for the update. i have commit .gitmodules as you said. can i know what field is missing here ?

Comment: You mean should i commit and push common-utitliy with my parent project rather than keeping reference link in parent project

Comment: I mean you should use `git submodule add` to add the submodule to your main repository.  It does more than just create a `.gitmodules` file; it creates a submodule object in the repository itself which is required for things to work.